# How to compare URI encoded strings?

Tags: python, http, encode

I was interviewed for a growing startup. One of the questions was regarding the URI encoding.

[W3.org](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2) says that these URIs are the same.
I changed abc with b93. I got this

```
>>> url4 = "http://b93.com:80/~smith/home.html"
>>> url5 = "http://b93.com/%7Esmith/home.html"
>>> urllib.parse.quote(url4)
'http%3A//b93.com%3A80/~smith/home.html'
>>> urllib.parse.quote(url5)
'http%3A//b93.com/%257Esmith/home.html'
```

How to compare encoded strings to get the right info? 
How to perform further testing?

I also tried JS with encodeURIComponenet()

```
var p1 = encodeURIComponent("http://b93.com:80/~smith/home.html");
var p2 = encodeURIComponent("http://b93.com/%7Esmith/home.html");

console.log(p1);
console.log(p2);
```

Output

```
http%3A%2F%2Fb93.com%3A80%2F~smith%2Fhome.html
http%3A%2F%2Fb93.com%2F%257Esmith%2Fhome.html
```

EDIT SOLVED

deceze suggested that I normalize my URL
Node.Js code

```
var normalizeUrl = require('normalize-url');

var n1 = normalizeUrl("http://b93.com:80/~smith/home.html");
var n2 = normalizeUrl("http://b93.com/%7Esmith/home.html");

console.log(n1);
console.log(n2);

var p1 = encodeURIComponent(n1);
var p2 = encodeURIComponent(n2);

console.log(p1);
console.log(p2);
```

Works fine

```
http://b93.com/~smith/home.html
http://b93.com/~smith/home.html
http%3A%2F%2Fb93.com%2F~smith%2Fhome.html
http%3A%2F%2Fb93.com%2F~smith%2Fhome.html
```

Comment: *Parse* the URL and then encode it to a canonical form (e.g. remove redundant information like `:80`). I.e., *normalize* the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it is first to ensure that you will compare unquoted URLs (by using `urllib.parse.unquote` instead of `urllib.parse.quote`). Then, you can use `urllib.parse.urlparse` to extract the main parts of the URL and compare them.

```
from urllib.parse import unquote, urlparse
url4 = "http://b93.com:80/~smith/home.html"
url4 = unquote(url4)
url5 = "http://b93.com/%7Esmith/home.html"
url5 = unquote(url5)
u4 = urlparse(url4)
u5 = urlparse(url5)
if u4.scheme == u5.scheme and u4.hostname == u5.hostname and u4.path == u5.path:
    print('equal')
else:
    print('different')
```

To be really sure, you may also want to compare the port by using the `scheme` to define the port when `port is None`.